# Save XML not working, or I'm just too tired

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, dom

I gotta be doing something stupid here, cause this code ain't workin

```
$semXML = new DOMDocument();
    $semXML->load('<rss></rss>');
    $midXML = $semXML->saveXML();       
    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
    file_put_contents($uploads['path'].$title.'.xml', $midXML);
```

It generates an XML file, but the only thing inside it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

any help is appreciated, been at this project for two days straight now o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $semXML->loadXML('<rss></rss>');
```

to load XML from a string. Just running `->load(...)` expects a file as parameter.

Comment: thank you, knew i was overlooking something relatively stupid.  time for sleep :)